# Targeting the information in a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to save the information (job) that a user enters into a form to a database, and then return the corresponding ID number from the database of that job.

I can successfully run a curl script of the 'create' method in terminal. However, when I enter text in my form that I have set up for the user, and hit 'submit' the data in the form disappears, and shows up in the browser after the slash after localhost...like so (http://localhost:7165/?URL=why+doesnt+this+work). No issue pops up in my console, so I think there is an issue with how the data in the dorm is being targeted. It may not be targeted at all since the event isn't happening.

How can I get the information entered on the form to save to my database and return an ID like I am able to using the curl script in terminal?

Here is my api:

```
'use strict'
// Use strict affects what config.apiOrigin does.
const config = require('../config.js')
const store = require('../store')

const addJob = function (data) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: config.apiOrigin + '/jobs',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data
  })
}

module.exports = {
  addJob
}
```

Here is my events.js:

```
const getFormFields = require('../../../lib/get-form-fields.js')
const api = require('./api.js')
const ui = require('./ui.js')

const onAddJobSubmit = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const data = getFormFields(event.target)
  api.addJob(data)
    .then(ui.onAddJobSuccess)
    .catch(ui.onAddJobFailure)
}

const eventListeners = function () {
  $('#URLForm').on('click', '#submitURLButton', onAddJobSubmit)
}
module.exports = {
  eventListeners
}
```

Here is my ui.js:

```
const onAddJobSuccess = function (data) {
  $('#URLForm').html('id')
}

const onAddJobFailure = function () {
  $('#URLForm').text('Job not added')
}

module.exports = {
  onAddJobSuccess,
  onAddJobFailure
}
```

* in the `onAddJobSuccess` I know that `id` is not the right way to display the ID of the job that has just been saved in the database, but I am still not sure how to target that ID.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body class="container-fluid">
      <h1>Job Queue</h1>
      <p>This app fetches HTML data from URLs and adds that HTML to a database. To begin a job, add a URL then click 'Submit'. </p>
      <div id="AddJob">
          <form id="URLForm">
              <div class="center">
                  <input name="URL" type="text" placeholder="URL" class="input-field">
                  <button id="submitURLButton">Submit</button>
              </div>
           </form>
           <div id="jobID">
               <div class="right">
                   <form id="returnID">
                   </form>
</body>
```

Comment: q1: Why not listen to the `submit` event on your form?
q2: What is the `data` argument showing when you log it out in `onAddJobSuccess`

Also is `onAddJobSuccess` meant to be changing the content of `form > #returnID` ?

Comment: I tried to log 'data' in onAddJobSuccess but the function won't run. Nothing at all shows up in my console except the initial GET request for loading the HTML

Comment: I think I should add a separate place to display the ID once it is retrieved, instead of replacing the information in the form with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Listen for a `submit` event on the form, not `click` and do not use event delegation.

```js
$('#URLForm').on('submit', onAddJobSubmit)
```

2. Use `<button type='submit`>